# Python/Beautiful Soup find particular heading output full div

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to parse a very extensive HTML document looks something like:

```html
<div class="reportsubsection n" ><br>
   <h2> part 1 </h2><br>
   <p> insert text here </p><br>
  <table> crazy table thing here </table><br>
</div>
<div class="reportsubsection n"><br>
   <h2> part 2 </h2><br>
   <p> insert text here </p><br>
   <table> crazy table thing here </table><br>
</div>
```

Need to parse out the second div based on h2 having text "Part 2". Iwas able to break out all divs with:

```
divTag = soup.find("div", {"id": "reportsubsection"})
```

but didn't know how to dwindle it down from there. Other posts I found I was able to find the specific text "part 2 but I need to be able to output the whole DIV section it is contained in.

EDIT/UPDATE

Ok sorry but I'm still a little lost. Here is what I've got now. I feel like this should be so much simpler than I'm making it. Thanks again for all the help

```
divTag = soup.find("div", {"id": "reportsubsection"})<br>
for reportsubsection in soup.select('div#reportsubsection #reportsubsection'):<br>
    if not reportsubsection.findAll('h2', text=re.compile('Finding')):<br>
        continue<br>
print divTag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always go back *up* after finding the right `h2`, or you can test all subsections:

```
for subsection in soup.select('div#reportsubsection #subsection'):
    if not subsection.find('h2', text=re.compile('part 2')):
        continue
    # do something with this subsection
```

This uses a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to locate all `subsection`s.

Or, going back up with the [`.parent` attribute](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent):

```
for header in soup.find_all('h2', text=re.compile('part 2')):
    section = header.parent
```

The trick is to narrow down your search as early as possible; the second option has to find all `h2` elements in the whole document, while the former narrows the search down quicker.

Comment: I like the second option (using `parent`) - looks simpler.

Comment: Also, `soup.find()` should be probably `soup.find_all()` (in the "parent" option)?

Comment: @alecxe: oops, yeah it should indeed use `.find_all()`; thanks.